# mySql Insert X Select Y fails while Select Y succeeds and Insert X "literal Y" succeeds as well

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-insert

mySql 5.6 -
OK: Select Extract(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2018 Thu',...
OK: Insert into T ...literal result of above select
FAILS: Insert into T Select Extract(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE ...
  with:"Data truncation: Truncated incorrect date value:"

Clearly, the third statement fails because the date string is too long for Extract. But I'm puzzled why the first statement doesn't fail as well.  See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a8b65  and uncomment lines 22-25 to see the 
failure I don't understand.

```
CREATE TABLE `Transactions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Period` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


Insert into Transactions ( `Period`)
Values 201809);

--EXTRACT doesn't fail with a longer string in SELECT
SELECT  
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM STR_TO_DATE('09/05/2018 Wed', '%m/%d/%Y'));

--Insert/EXTRACT works fine with shorter string
Insert into Transactions (  `Period`)
Values(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM 
               STR_TO_DATE('09/06/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')
              )); 

--This fails, why?      
Insert into Transactions (  `Period`)
Values(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM 
               STR_TO_DATE('09/07/2018 Fri', '%m/%d/%Y')
              ));
```

Comment: This: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=bbf3244dbb3a149338562ec565f2fdef works fine.

Comment: Works fine in [this MySQL 5.6 db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xyDbYzRgqDdmnA6aPT5f9M/0) too. Looks like this issue is not reproducible.

Comment: I outsmarted myself trying to strip down the problem to its essentials, and stripped too much. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a8b65  runs, then uncomment lines 22-25 and it fails. And that's my puzzle.